# How to extract mp4 video from m3u8 file

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, m3u8

I have been downloading videos from a website recently using either Chrome extensions or a downloading site. However, recently it has started to give a `m3u8` file download link. I have searched all over internet and tried numerous methods but am unable to download these videos. Does anyone have an idea of how to get the download links of such videos?

Most of these videos are highlights of football matches that normally play in the browser but cannot be downloaded.

This is the error I get when i use FFmpeg:

```
http @ 0000018479631d00] Protocol 'http' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
master.m3u8: Invalid argument
```

Comment: You should be able to play and download using VLC or FFMPEG.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i 'url' -c copy 'outputFile.mp4'`

Answer (score 5):

`m3u8` files are usually text files that contain links to the actual data files.

A solution I use, is to download the actual data files with `curl` in a Bash loop and then concatenate all the downloaded files of the playlist.

You can try a Bash function like the following [put it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file and edit it accordingly if you need to]:

```
function download-playlist() {
    if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
        touch ./files.txt;
        counter=1;
        while read line; do
            if [[ "$line" == "http"* ]]; then
                curl --silent -o ${counter}.mp4 "$line";
                echo "file ${counter}.mp4" >> ./files.txt;
                ((counter++));
            fi;
        done < "$1";
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i ./files.txt -codec copy output.mp4;
    else
        echo 'Usage: download-playlist <file.m3u8>';
    fi
}
```

Then you can use it like this: `download-playlist master.m3u8`

PS: Usually the `master.m3u8` contains links to sub-playlists. The function possibly must be run on a sub-playlist and not on the actual `master.m3u8` playlist.

Comment: Nice answer! Do you mind fixing ffmpeg call? There's a missing 'f' :)

Comment: Nice answer! The ffmpeg option `-safe 0` is not necessary in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream a M3U8 video using the free [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) if you have a link to the to the `.m3u8` file. VLC
can also convert the a M3U8 video to MP4 or another desired video format.

Alternate conversion and download methods can be found in [this article](https://www.minitool.com/video-converter/m3u8-to-mp4.html).

**Playing/streaming M3U8 with VLC**

If you have a local `.m3u8` file you can play this in VLC as you would any other video format supported by VLC.

If you do not have an `.m3u8` file locally but you have a link to the file you wish to view, these are the steps to stream the video:

1. Open VLC
2. Select **Media** from the VLC menu bar, and then choose **Stream...** (or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut)
3. In the dialog box that appears, select the **Network** tab
4. Paste the URL into the text box, and press the **Stream** button
5. Press **Next** until the dialog box closes
6. After taking some time to buffer, your video should begin streaming

**Converting a M3U8 video in a different video format**

If you want to convert a `.m3u8` file that you have downloaded to some other video format, follow the instructions below:

1. Open VLC
2. Select **Media** from the VLC menu bar, and then choose **Convert / Save...** (or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut)
3. In the dialog box that appears, press the **Add...** tab
4. Select the `.m3u8` video file you want to convert
5. Click on **Convert / Save**
6. Select the desired output video format from the **Profile** dropdown menu
7. Press the **Browse** button to select where the converted video file should be stored on your computer
8. Press the **Start** button to begin the conversion
9. VLC will show a progress bar indicating its progress with the conversion. Do not close VLC until the conversion has completed.

Answer (score -1):

I have found out the answer. The problem is that the stream is encrypted and using FFmpeg I run into an error that is **SAMPLE-AES encryption is not supported yet**. So unless FFmpeg supports this feature, such videos could not be downloaded.

Comment: VLC can handle AES encryption. If you're up for programming yourself, any language can solve the problem.

Comment: @Enrico do you mean the vlc or the programming solution? IIRC vlc will automatically handle encryption. Regarding the DIY way, I wrote about how I solved a similar issue here: https://andreasvolkmann.github.io/posts/2018-04-27-m3u8-and-ts-segments/